# UnicodeEncodeError: character maps to <undefined> for write in archive python

Tags: python, file, unicode, utf-8

I have a problem with this code I'm running in jupyter notebbok (and VS code too) with Python. I have a .cvs file that I read through the input below (The .split() serves only to indicate when it reaches the end of a line within the file):

```
dumpfile = "./code.csv"
input = open(dumpfile , 'r', -1, encoding="utf-8").read().split('[||END||]')
```

Below is an example of the code.csv content:

```
87[||||]2125[||||]
bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla[||END||]
8[||||]2598[||||]
bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla[||END||]
```

Well, I read the items that are in the file using the code below (so far everything is correct).

```
for line in input:
  data = line.split('[||||]')
  if (len(data) > 1):
    id_one = int(data[0]) #they are int
    id_two = int(data[1]) #they are int
    id_tree = data[2] #they are str only
    functionDIRECTONE(id_one, id_two, id_tree)
```

I send each one read by parameter to another function, and in this function, the goal is to create directories for each of the elements read.

```
def functionDIRECTONE(id_one, id_two, id_tree):
    path_code = "./code_complete/"
    checkNAMES = str (id_one)
    code_student = str (id_two)

    #here creates directory
    if not os.path.isdir(path_code +checkNAMES):
        path = path_code +checkNAMES
        os.mkdir(path)

    #here creates the files inside the directories created previously
    exer_atual = str (id_two)
    if os.path.isdir(path_code+checkNAMES):
        if checkNAMES == exer_atual:
            exer_aluno = str (id_one)
            arquivo = open(path_code+checkNAMES+"/"+exer_aluno+".txt","w")
            arquivo.write(id_tree)
```

The code works until the moment when it arrives at `arquivo.write(id_tree)`, it gives the following error:

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in encode(self, input, final)
     17 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
     18     def encode(self, input, final=False):
---> 19         return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
     20 
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2212' in position 237: character maps to <undefined>
```

The error appears when writing into the file. I have already looked for solutions, but I am told that it is a console error (and "utf-8" was already assigned at the beginning), but I am not printing but writing in the file. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This is happening on `arquivo.write(id_tree)`? What is `sys.getdefaultencoding()`? Can you just add an encoding to the output file `arquivo = open(path_code+checkNAMES+"/"+exer_aluno+".txt","w", encoding="utf-8")`?

Comment: We know the problem character is `'\u2212'`. As a test, this problem may boil down to `open('test.txt', 'w').write('\u2212')`

Comment: Apparently it worked @tdelaney, it worked by putting "encoding =" utf-8 "at the end of `arquivo = open(path_code+checkNAMES+"/"+exer_aluno+".txt","w", encoding="utf-8")`. As soon as I finish compiling I'll let you know. Thanks.